# I couldnt genarate view binding in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-viewbinding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5kc0.png)

When I try genarate view binding for kotlin, its giving red line on inflate and I cannot run project.

```
package com.example.wiewbinding

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.renderscript.ScriptGroup.Binding
import com.example.wiewbinding.databinding.ActivityMainBinding



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

    }
}
```

How to fix that?

Android doc is not work properly I think. We have to find way to use

Comment: "its giving red line on inflate" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to import it explicitly.
Check once, if in build.gradle file, is the view Binding is enabled or not.
After this rebuild it and check if the red line issue is resolve or not and let me know

Comment: I opened a new project and changed its name. I applied the same way, it's working correctly. Idk why. Thx for your help